# How to change the pageviwer indicator position?

Tags: java, android

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">

          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
              android:id="@+id/viewpager_default"
              android:repeatCount="infinite"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

       <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator_default"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

This my layout and now it is showing in the center of the page viwer how could i change to bottom help me,and if remove the android:layout_centerInParent="true" line it will show to the top

Answer (score 1):

As you had kept `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `CircleIndicator` it will show in Center of the `RelativeLayout` only.

You need to set your `CircleIndicator` `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and set your `ViewPager` to `android:layout_above="@+id/indicator_default"` your indicator.

**Try with Following Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/indicator_default"
            android:repeatCount="infinite" />

        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator_default"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works but there is problem there is a white box shown in bottom.

Comment: @VAISAKHPVR as you had given 40dp height to indicators and width as fill_parent i had changed them please check with new code.

Comment: oops its total style is changed please checkout the screens of old and new one https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6trf6ee23mp1n0/Please%20review.rar?dl=0

Comment: @VAISAKHPVR I had changed height and width of CircleIndicator and added padding to it please check with updated code

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreateView() method:

```
 //Set the pager with an adapter
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

 //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
 CircleIndicator circleIndicator= (CircleIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
 circleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

For more detail please use below link:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Thanks for your answer please checkout this screens https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6trf6ee23mp1n0/Please%20review.rar?dl=0